# SignalR Hub - Check for incoming or outgoing data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I want to implement the feature to properly shut down all SignalR hubs before shutting down the server, to roll out a new application version.

I want the REST API to finish all currently managed requests but not to accept new requests. That's already implemented.

Also, I want to shut down all hubs. The problem is that a REST requests connection is closed when it's done, so it's easy to determine if there are still requests, that have to be finished. But a Hub connection is always active unless it's closed on purpose or something went wrong.

So I want to shut down the hub if no data is currently transmitted. Is there a way to check for this information?

Comment: We often use hub methods to pass data to server,since you want to check if there is incomming or outgoing data,you can try to use [hub filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hub-filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to check the hub method which passed the data.